# Как изменить базу для миграции в Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Вот пользователи БД:

```
    Role name    |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 mrkrot617       |                                                            | {}
 postgres        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 project-manager | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
mrkrot617@mrkrot617-X507UA:~/repositories/project-manager$ heroku run rake db:setup
Running rake db:setup on ⬢ project-manager-mrkrot617... up, run.2436 (Free)
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
Couldn't create 'dbphamj9cgfqjr' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Вот код из database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: project-manager
  password: 1234
```

База создалась:

```
mrkrot617@mrkrot617-X507UA:~/repositories/project-manager$ rake db:create
Created database 'project-manager_development'
Created database 'project-manager_test'
```

Что не так? Проект голый, из коробки. На локальной машине сайт работает.

UPD: Если я правильно понял, heroku пытается проводить операции со стандартной базой postgres, а я же хочу, чтобы моя база project-manager_development мигрировала в heroku. Как заставить heroku обращаться к моей базе, а не к базе postgres?

```
                                                     Список баз данных
             Имя             |    Владелец     | Кодировка | LC_COLLATE  |  LC_CTYPE   |           Права доступа           
-----------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------
 postgres                    | postgres        | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | postgres=CTc/postgres            +
                             |                 |           |             |             | mrkrot617=CTc/postgres           +
                             |                 |           |             |             | =CTc/postgres                    +
                             |                 |           |             |             | "project-manager"=CTc/postgres   +
                             |                 |           |             |             | pg_monitor=CTc/postgres          +
                             |                 |           |             |             | pg_read_all_stats=CTc/postgres   +
                             |                 |           |             |             | pg_read_all_settings=CTc/postgres+
                             |                 |           |             |             | pg_signal_backend=CTc/postgres   +
                             |                 |           |             |             | pg_stat_scan_tables=CTc/postgres
 project-manager_development | project-manager | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | 
 project-manager_test        | project-manager | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | 
 template0                   | postgres        | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                      +
                             |                 |           |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1                   | postgres        | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                      +
                             |                 |           |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не там искал проблему. Нужно просто сделать правильные миграции с локальной машины на Heroku и запустить

```
rails db:migrate
heroku rake db:migrate
```